# Bash script, array not getting created as expected

Tags: bash, shell

I'm pretty new to bash scripting and I'm obviously missing some fairly basic understanding as I can't work out why this script isn't doing as I'd expect. I've made a simple example reproducing the problem, it is supposed to make 3 folders, with 3 folders inside, then touch a file `test` inside of each.

Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
DIR_LEVEL_1=("1" "2" "3")
for DIR_1 in ${DIR_LEVEL_1[@]}; do
  mkdir $DIR_1
  DIR_LEVEL_2=("$DIR_1/a" "$DIR_1/b" "$DIR_1/c")
  echo $DIR_LEVEL_2
  for DIR_2 in ${DIR_LEVEL2[@]}; do
    mkdir $DIR_2
    touch "$DIR_2/test"
  done
done
```

The problem I was having was the it wasn't entering the second for loop, I put in that echo and it looks like the second array isn't being created properly as the output of the script is:

```
1/a
2/a
3/a
```

which is just the first element of the array.

running with `-xv` flag I get this, which shows it's taking no notice of that nested for loop (I guess because the array didn't get created as I wanted?)

```
#!/bin/sh
DIR_LEVEL_1=("1" "2" "3")
+ DIR_LEVEL_1=("1" "2" "3")
for DIR_1 in ${DIR_LEVEL_1[@]}; do
  mkdir $DIR_1
  DIR_LEVEL_2=("$DIR_1/a" "$DIR_1/b" "$DIR_1/c")
  echo $DIR_LEVEL_2
  for DIR_2 in ${DIR_LEVEL2[@]}; do
    mkdir $DIR_2
    touch "$DIR_2/test"
  done
done
+ for DIR_1 in '${DIR_LEVEL_1[@]}'
+ mkdir 1
+ DIR_LEVEL_2=("$DIR_1/a" "$DIR_1/b" "$DIR_1/c")
+ echo 1/a
1/a
+ for DIR_1 in '${DIR_LEVEL_1[@]}'
+ mkdir 2
+ DIR_LEVEL_2=("$DIR_1/a" "$DIR_1/b" "$DIR_1/c")
+ echo 2/a
2/a
+ for DIR_1 in '${DIR_LEVEL_1[@]}'
+ mkdir 3
+ DIR_LEVEL_2=("$DIR_1/a" "$DIR_1/b" "$DIR_1/c")
+ echo 3/a
3/a
```

So it only creates the first level of folders

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the real issue with your script is that you create `DIR_LEVEL_2`, but you iterate over `DIR_LEVEL2`. (Note the underscore difference). However, you also neglect to quote `"${array[@]}"`, which means it will not wordsplit properly. All that aside, might I suggest you use brace expansion to make this entire thing a better experience?

```
#!/bin/bash

dirs=( {1,2,3}/{a,b,c} )
mkdir -p "${dirs[@]}"
for d in "${dirs[@]}"; do
    touch "$d/test"
done
```

Edit/postscript: I notice your script above uses `#!/bin/sh`, but you've tagged this post `bash`. They are not the same thing. Unless you're certain you want to trade the greater featureset of bash for the greater portability of sh, use `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: No need for the loop: mkdir -p {1,2,3}/{a,b,c}; touch {1,2,3}/{a,b,c}/test

Comment: @WilliamPursell very true. I wanted to leave an example of looping properly (including quoting the array expansion) intact, but I should've mentioned that the loop is unnecessary for the actual task at hand.

Answer (score 4):

You have three problems here:

1. The script should start with `#!/bin/bash` if you want to use bash, not `#!/bin/sh`
2. `echo $ARRAY` will output only the first element of the array, not the whole array, which is why it looks like it is doing only the first element - it is not, but it is just printing the first. Use `echo ${ARRAY[@]}` to output the whole array.
3. When you are iterating the second array, you have the variable name wrong. Your array is `DIR_LEVEL_2`, but you are iterating `${DIR_LEVEL2[@]}`, which is empty (hence no iteration). You are missing an underscore before the `2`

Comment: Ah thanks! I was confused as I'd expect some sort of error typically for undefined variables. I also got a bit stuck with another mistake I made in my main script which didn't make it to the sample which was putting a space after the `=` when declaring a variable, I didn't realise you couldn't do that!

Comment: Shell syntax is unusually picky about spaces, etc, because it has to coexist with executing commands.  Thus, `foo = bar` runs the command `foo` with two arguments, `=` and `bar`, while `foo=bar` is an assignment.

If you want an error when you access an undefined variable, add `set  -u` to the top of your script.